# Pset 1 (Mario Less Hard)

Tags: c, cs50

This program doesnt run its just asks for the height and then nothing furthers from there.When I ran check 50 it instructed me the values like foo and other a are taken in so I replaced printf with a scanf and everything stopped working.

Also can someone guide me on how to make the program keep asking for height inbetween 2 and 8 untill its true ? As of not now it sends out a message to enter a number between 2 & 8 and stops.

```
int main()
{
    int height;
    do {
        height =get_int("Height: ");
        scanf("%d", &height);

        if ( height<1 || height>8) { 
            printf ("Kindly Enter A Number Between 2 & 8 !\n"); 
            return 0;
        }

    }
    while (height <1 || height>8);

    for(int i=0; i<height ; i++) // Row Number
    {
        for (int j=0; j<height ;j++)
        {
            if (i+j >= height-1)
            printf("#");

            else 
                printf (" ");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

}
```

Comment: Why the C# tag? Should that have been C?

Comment: Sorry my bad.
Rectified the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `return 0;` statement in the `if` statement. `return` statements in the `main` function immediately terminate the program.

Answer (score 0):

why are taking `height` two times:

```
        height =get_int("Height: ");
        scanf("%d", &height);
```

this is sufficient : `scanf("%d", &height);`.

also always check the return of `scanf`.

and as mentioned remove `return 0` because otherwise when you reach it, your program will end immediately.

I assume what you want is something like this:

```
    int height;
    do {
        if (scanf("%d", &height) == 1);//checking the result of scanf function
        else
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

        if (height < 1 || height>8) {
            printf("Kindly Enter A Number Between 2 & 8 !\n");
            //removing return 0
        }

    }
    while (height < 1 || height>8);
```